# solving equation with limit: $1+x =\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{y}{n})^n => y = \lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+x)^\frac{1}{n} - 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

I'm trying to understand a part of logarithmic series expansion proof below:

The logarithmic function is the inverse of the exponential function, so that

$y=ln(1+x)$ implies $1+x=e^y = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{y}{n})^n$

Unscrambling the limit to solve for $y$ gives

$y = \lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+x)^\frac{1}{n} - 1)$

... I can't understand the "unscrambling the limit to solve for y" part, i.e.

$1+x = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{y}{n})^n => y = \lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+x)^\frac{1}{n} - 1)$

I'd be happy to see an explanation of the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets (or the source's, I have no way to know) are wrong. The expression should be
$$
\log(1+x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,n\big[(1+x)^{1/n}-1\big].
$$
And this is simply, with $z=1+x$
$$
n\big[z^{1/n}-1\big]=n\big[e^{\frac1n\log z}-1\big]
=n\,\big[\frac1n\log z+o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)\big]
=\log z+o\big(\frac1n).
$$
So in the limit you get $\log z=\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I messed up with the formulas. I've fixed the question, thank you